# Asynchronous task in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-deeplens

I am currently working on a python project for a DeepLens camera on AWS. I try to save images, put them in a list and in parallel add them to AWS S3.

When the image capture and sends it to S3 work sequentially, everything works. It's when I try to run both functions asynchronously it doesn't work anymore.

Indeed, only one of the two threads starts: I capture images but I can't send them to S3.

Do you think it is necessary to use another library than the threads or that the error comes from my code.

Thank you.

```
#*****************************************************
#                                                    *
# Copyright 2018 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. *
# All Rights Reserved.                               *
#                                                    *
#*****************************************************
""" A sample lambda for face detection"""
from threading import Thread, Event, Timer
import os
import json
import numpy as np
import awscam
import cv2
import greengrasssdk
import boto3
from botocore.session import Session
import time

# ----------------------------------- Function ------------------------------------

liste_of_frame = []


def write_image_to_s3(img):
    session = Session()
    s3 = session.create_client('s3')
    file_name = 'DeepLens/image-'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+'.jpg'
    # You can contorl the size and quality of the image
    encode_param=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),100]
    _, jpg_data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img, encode_param)
    response = s3.put_object(ACL='public-read', Body=jpg_data.tostring(),Bucket='deeplens-sagemaker-f2e',Key=file_name)
    image_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/deeplens-sagemaker-f2e/'+file_name
    return image_url


def upload_image():
    client.publish(topic=iot_topic, payload='upload_image')
    if len(liste_of_frame) > 0:
        for i,img in enumerate(liste_of_frame):
            write_image_to_s3(img)
            try:
                liste_of_frame.pop(i)
            except:
                pass
    return liste_of_frame



def capture_img(model_type, output_map, client, iot_topic, local_display, model_path, model, detection_threshold, input_height, input_width):

            # client.publish(topic=iot_topic, payload='inside function')
            ret, frame = awscam.getLastFrame()
            if not ret:
                raise Exception('Failed to get frame from the stream')

            # Resize frame to the same size as the training set.
            frame_resize = cv2.resize(frame, (input_height, input_width))
            # Run the images through the inference engine and parse the results using
            # the parser API, note it is possible to get the output of doInference
            # and do the parsing manually, but since it is a ssd model,
            # a simple API is provided.
            parsed_inference_results = model.parseResult(model_type,
                                                         model.doInference(frame_resize))
            # Compute the scale in order to draw bounding boxes on the full resolution
            # image.
            yscale = float(frame.shape[0]/input_height)
            xscale = float(frame.shape[1]/input_width)
            # Dictionary to be filled with labels and probabilities for MQTT
            cloud_output = {}
            # Get the detected faces and probabilities
            for obj in parsed_inference_results[model_type]:
                if obj['prob'] > detection_threshold:
                    cloud_output[output_map[obj['label']]] = obj['prob']
                    # client.publish(topic=iot_topic, payload='Ajout a la liste')
                    liste_of_frame.append(frame)


            # Set the next frame in the local display stream.
            local_display.set_frame_data(frame)
            # Send results to the cloud
            # client.publish(topic=iot_topic, payload=json.dumps(cloud_output))



def init_greengrass():

        # This face detection model is implemented as single shot detector (ssd).
        model_type = 'ssd'
        output_map = {1: 'face'}
        # Create an IoT client for sending to messages to the cloud.
        client = greengrasssdk.client('iot-data')
        iot_topic = '$aws/things/{}/infer'.format(os.environ['AWS_IOT_THING_NAME'])
        # Create a local display instance that will dump the image bytes to a FIFO
        # file that the image can be rendered locally.
        local_display = LocalDisplay('480p')
        local_display.start()
        # The sample projects come with optimized artifacts, hence only the artifact
        # path is required.
        model_path = '/opt/awscam/artifacts/mxnet_deploy_ssd_FP16_FUSED.xml'
        # Load the model onto the GPU.
        client.publish(topic=iot_topic, payload='Loading face detection model')
        model = awscam.Model(model_path, {'GPU': 1})
        client.publish(topic=iot_topic, payload='Face detection model loaded')
        # Set the threshold for detection
        detection_threshold = 0.5
        # The height and width of the training set images
        input_height = 300
        input_width = 300

        return model_type, output_map, client, iot_topic, local_display, model_path, model, detection_threshold, input_height, input_width


# --------------------------------------- End Function -----------------------------------        



class LocalDisplay(Thread):
    """ Class for facilitating the local display of inference results
        (as images). The class is designed to run on its own thread. In
        particular the class dumps the inference results into a FIFO
        located in the tmp directory (which lambda has access to). The
        results can be rendered using mplayer by typing:
        mplayer -demuxer lavf -lavfdopts format=mjpeg:probesize=32 /tmp/results.mjpeg
    """
    def __init__(self, resolution):
        """ resolution - Desired resolution of the project stream """
        # Initialize the base class, so that the object can run on its own
        # thread.
        super(LocalDisplay, self).__init__()
        # List of valid resolutions
        RESOLUTION = {'1080p' : (1920, 1080), '720p' : (1280, 720), '480p' : (858, 480)}
        if resolution not in RESOLUTION:
            raise Exception("Invalid resolution")
        self.resolution = RESOLUTION[resolution]
        # Initialize the default image to be a white canvas. Clients
        # will update the image when ready.
        self.frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', 255*np.ones([640, 480, 3]))[1]
        self.stop_request = Event()

    def run(self):
        """ Overridden method that continually dumps images to the desired
            FIFO file.
        """
        # Path to the FIFO file. The lambda only has permissions to the tmp
        # directory. Pointing to a FIFO file in another directory
        # will cause the lambda to crash.
        result_path = '/tmp/results.mjpeg'
        # Create the FIFO file if it doesn't exist.
        if not os.path.exists(result_path):
            os.mkfifo(result_path)
        # This call will block until a consumer is available
        with open(result_path, 'w') as fifo_file:
            while not self.stop_request.isSet():
                try:
                    # Write the data to the FIFO file. This call will block
                    # meaning the code will come to a halt here until a consumer
                    # is available.
                    fifo_file.write(self.frame.tobytes())
                except IOError:
                    continue

    def set_frame_data(self, frame):
        """ Method updates the image data. This currently encodes the
            numpy array to jpg but can be modified to support other encodings.
            frame - Numpy array containing the image data tof the next frame
                    in the project stream.
        """
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cv2.resize(frame, self.resolution))

        if not ret:
            raise Exception('Failed to set frame data')
        self.frame = jpeg

    def join(self):
        self.stop_request.set()

def greengrass_infinite_infer_run():
    """ Entry point of the lambda function"""
    try:
        model_type, output_map, client, iot_topic, local_display, model_path, model, detection_threshold, input_height, input_width = init_greengrass()
        # Do inference until the lambda is killed.
        while True:

            t1 = Thread(target = capture_img, args=[model_type, output_map, client, iot_topic, local_display, model_path, model, detection_threshold, input_height, input_width])
            t2 = Thread(target = upload_image)
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()


    except Exception as ex:
        client.publish(topic=iot_topic, payload='Error in face detection lambda: {}'.format(ex))

greengrass_infinite_infer_run()
```

Comment: I don't see any print/logging statements in this code that will help you to understand what is going on when run as a Lambda function.

Comment: It's published in the iot topic service : client.publish(topic=iot_topic, payload='Loading face detection model')